# Possible to get old data from onChildChanged? (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to get the old data from onChildChanged() before firing? I need to check 2 values against each other.

Is there a way around this? Thank you.

```
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onChildChanged` only gets a snapshot of the updated data. If you need the previous state too, you'll have to ensure you catch it in the listener at an earlier time and keep it in your app's state.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there an example?

Comment: Nope. But to be honest, it shouldn't be much more than having a variable `previousSnapshot` and assigning that in `onDataChange` after you're done with other processing.

Answer (score 0):

If `previousSnapshot` is not useful, then consider using a local HashMap or an ArrayList. Something like this:

```
// Initialize a global arraylist of your custom `MyPostSnapshot` object
ArrayList<MyPostSnapshot> listOfPostSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();

// Then inside your `onChildChanged`, add the item
@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        MyPostSnapshot myPostSnapshot = new MyPostSnapshot();
        myPostSnaoshot.setSomeValue(dataSnapshot.child("someChild").getValue());
        listOfPostSnapshots.add(myPostSnapshot);
    }
}
```

You can get the previous dataSnapshot that you saved by simply accessing the last item in the ArrayList like this: `listOfPostSnapshots.get(listOfPostSnapshots.size() - 1)`

Comment: I'm using an array list. Just not sure how to even start writing the code for saving the previous snapshot